# PHP srlen outputs correct number but if statement returns false?

Tags: php

The following echo outputs 8 yet my if statement returns false? is_numeric works fine alone however I cannot figure out why strlen wont return true.

```
echo strlen($_POST['results']);
if (is_numeric($_POST['results']) && strlen($_POST['results'] == 8)) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, your parens are messed-up :

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['results']) && ( strlen($_POST['results']) == 8) ) {
```

Comment: @TaylorReed m'pleasure : if the answer helped, show it !